# Set tfoot position

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

Is it possible to style the tfoot section of a table so it shows between the thead and tbody?

I would like to get a table to look like this:

[image]

Comment: That wouldn't quite make it a table footer, would it?

Comment: I agree, totally silly, but this seems like the easiest way to make a change I want to how I'm using datatables.net.

Comment: I ended up fixing my problem without using tfoot.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per my comment, you probably don't want to be making a table footer appear as anything other than a table footer.

But assuming you have the properly-ordered markup, this should work in whatever browser supports it:

```
thead, tfoot {
    display: table-header-group;
}
```

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/Shypj)

Comment: But the TFoot is not appearing in the middle?

Comment: @Jawad: If it's not, the browser doesn't support it. I'm trying to look into why I can't get the demo working on any version of IE, even though sources say it supports `table-header-group` on at least `thead` and `tfoot`...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S3PyC/)

Comment: This totally breaks the layout of the table, cells no longer share widths with other cells in the same column, etc.